# Multiple actions matched

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-2.1

I have migrated to `ASP.NET Core 2.1`.I'd like to submit a form (Insert method from ArticleController: url: http://localhost:52125/article/insert) but I got this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
>   actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Controllers.ArticleController.Insert
>   (Jahan.Beta.Web.App)
>   Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Controllers.ArticleController.Edit
>   (Jahan.Beta.Web.App)
>   Jahan.Beta.Web.App.Controllers.ArticleController.DeleteConfirmed
>   (Jahan.Beta.Web.App)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector.SelectBestCandidate(RouteContext
>   context, IReadOnlyList candidates)

How can I solve it? and is there a way to improve/optimize routes.MapRoute?

**Article Controller:**

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ArticleController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Insert([FromBody]Article article)
   {
      // I want to run this method!
   }

   [HttpGet("Edit/{id}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
   {
   }
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [FromBody] Article article)
   {
   }

   [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteConfirmed/{id}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
   {
   }
}
```

**a part of startup.cs file:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        provider.Mappings[".less"] = "plain/text";

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ContentTypeProvider = provider
        });

        ApplicationDbContext.CreateAdminAccount(app.ApplicationServices, Configuration).Wait();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminAreasUsers",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Users}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminAreasDeleteUser",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Users}/{action=Delete}/{id}"
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "FilterByTagAsync",
               template: "{controller}/{action}/{tagId}/{articlePage}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "FilterByTagAsync", tagId = "", articlePage = "" }
           );
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ShowArticle",
               template: "{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Show", Id = "" }
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller}/{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
           );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "About",
                template: "{Controller=AboutUs}/{action=AboutUs}/{id?}");

        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the route that you are posting to?

Comment: from  /Article/Create url I want to submit a form that method is on /Article/Insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using attribute-based routing, but haven't applied any routes to any of those actions. As such, they're all using the default of `""`, or an empty route. You need to do something like:

```
[HttpPost("insert")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Insert([FromBody]Article article)

[HttpGet("Edit/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)

[HttpPost("edit/{id}")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [FromBody] Article article)

[HttpPost("delete"), ActionName("DeleteConfirmed/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
```

Comment: I applied them but I got this error "Status Code: 415; Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: That's an *entirely* different issue. You've now fixed the issue in your question, but you have another issue that now needs to be fixed as well. You should really open a new question for that. However, I will say that that is a result of the request body encoding. For example, if you're posting XML without having enabled the XML serializers, there's your problem.

Comment: I removed [FromBody]  from Insert method and now is OK!